# Inductive Proof of $n! < n^n$

Tags: inequality, induction

Looking at the Wikipedia page on [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Variants), I see that $n! < \frac{n^n}{2^n}\; \forall n>6$
I have been trying to prove that $n! < n^n \; \forall n>5$ using induction myself and my result is a clear special case of the above inequality. Does anyone have any hints on how to show either of these using induction? This came up when a student inquired about proving the convergence of a series, and induction seemed easier to show than a proof using Stirling's Approximation, but I can't seem to find a proof.

Comment: Don't use induction, the result is clear if $n\ge 2$. For $n!$ is the product of $n$ numbers, all $\le n$, and some $\ne n$. And $n^n$ is the product of $n$ numbers all equal to $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, $n!<n^n$ for $n>1$. The case $n=2$ is proved by inspection.

Suppose $n!<n^n$, for $n\ge2$; then $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!<(n+1)n^n$.

Moreover, from $n<n+1$, we deduce $n^n<(n+1)^n$. So we're done.

---

For $n!<n^n/2^n$, it's true only for $n>5$: indeed $6!=720$, while $6^6/2^6=729$.

So assume $n!<n^n/2^n$, for $n\ge6$. Then
$$
(n+1)!=(n+1)n!<(n+1)\frac{n^n}{2^n}
$$
and so we need to prove that
$$
(n+1)\frac{n^n}{2^n}\le\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
2n^n\le (n+1)^n=n^n+\binom{n}{1}n^{n-1}+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}n^{n-k}
$$
and this is clearly true.

Comment: Beautiful second proof, thanks for helping! Not sure how I missed such a simple induction for the first proof, but the second is really interesting... nice use of the binomial theorem

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Show $(n+1)n^n < (n+1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Fill in the details:

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!<(n+1)n^n<(n+1)(n+1)^n=(n+1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really thought it was the easiest to understand. Quick follow up, does the following hold as well as an extension of your proof?   
 
$$\text{Suppose } n! < n^{n-2}$$
$$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! < (n+1)n^{n-2} < (n+1)(n+1)^{n-2} = (n+1)^{n-1} $$

Comment: Yes, it does! But only if you find the appropiate base case (for that, $n\geq 5$ suffices).

I think it's even true that $n!<n^{n-m}$ for whatever fixed $m\in \Bbb N$ if you carefully pick your base case.

Answer (score 1):

$$\underbrace{n!=1*2*3\; ...*\;n}_{n\text{ digits}}$$

$$\underbrace{n^n=n*n*n\;...*\;n}_{n\text{ digits}}$$

Start with the first digit in each and proceed until reaching $n$.

$$1<n$$
$$2<n$$
$$3<n$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n=n$$

This should make it obvious that $n!<n^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+1+...+1)^{n}$ use multinomial expansion formula
Then $(1+1+...+1)^{n}>{n\choose{1}{1}{...}{1}}$

Comment: haha, yeah. That would do it, even if it is sorta nuking the fly XD This post was a while back... can't say I need the help anymore, and I could definitely answer this myself now, but it's always fun to see a creative answer on an old post!

Comment: I am the new user, seeing the post for the first time. Tried to give different answer. Then Binomiamial expansion clicked on my mind. Then I generalize it.